How to work with relations between collections in Isar Flutter?
I am trying to generate .g.dart files to work with Isar in flutter.I have two collections InnerList and OuterList, and I want to have a relation between these two collections. When I am running the build command the .g.dart file for InnerList collection is generated but i am facing a problem with the outerList collection. Please let me know where am I going wrong here. I am facing an issue with IsarLinks between the collections OuterList and InnerList.
I am getting the following error(please follow the link)
Image of the error I am facing
These are the collections
import 'package:dummy_database_project/models/inner_list.dart';
import 'package:isar/isar.dart';
part 'outer_list.g.dart';


@Collection()
class OuterList {
  Id id = Isar.autoIncrement;
  late String title;
  final IsarLinks <InnerList> innerList;

  OuterList(this.innerList);
}

import 'package:isar/isar.dart';
part 'inner_list.g.dart';

@Collection()
class InnerList {
  Id id = Isar.autoIncrement;
  late String devicename;
  late String deviceUrl;
  late int siteId;
}


Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question. Also take the [tour].

https://pub.dev/packages/isar read the documentation. and you'll see in 2nd step using @embedded to make relation between two.

I did try that but I also need the id for innerlist. When we annotate with embedded it won't allow us to use the Id field. Which is why I thought using IsarLinks will give me any solution.
